# Joomla 3 - how are translations linked in db

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I'm creating a custom migration script and I'm trying to figure out where is the link between articles in multiple languages stored in DB in Joomla 3

Anyone knows?

Answer (score -1):

For anyone needing this, I found the answer myself. The relationship is saved in the `_asociations` table, with `id` being article ID, `'the 'context' = 'com_content.item'` and `key` the link between translations...

Comment: Always funny to see a correct answer to a valid question downvoted...:)